# How to change a specific entity of a specific record stored in a file in c++

Tags: c++

Hi friends i want to modify a specific entity of a specific record stored in file. like i have stored record in file as

Roll No: 35

Name: Adnan Irshad

Status: Not Admitted

Roll No: 40

Name: Adeel Ahmed

Status: Not Admitted

Roll No: 30

Name: Arish

Adnan: Not Admitted

Roll No: 35

Name: Shan

Status: Not Admitted

Here i want to search the record via roll no and change the status of that record to admitted like i input 
30 roll no to search the record and then program search that record and change its status to admitted.
I have done this but my code only change the one record when i do this for another record then nothing happen.
code is here

```
    char stat[13];

    cout<<"Enter Registration No";

    cin>>reg_no;

    fstream out("Intermediate.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::app);

    out.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    out.read((char*)&std,sizeof(std));

    while(!out.eof())

     {  

        record_no++;

        if(strcmp(std.get_reg_no(),reg_no)==0)

        {

            found=1;

            break;

        }

     }

    location=(record_no-1)*sizeof(std);

    out.seekp(location,ios::beg);

    char new_status[]="Addmitted"; // initialized to replace with status

    strcpy(std.status,new_status);

    out.write((char*)&std,sizeof(std));

    out.close();
```

Comment: Your code looks messy. The use of `goto` raises a potential danger as the code flow may get dangled during runtime. We don't even see where the `voucher` label is. Where exactly do update `found` to `0`? What initialization value does it have? Plus, you may only post snippet code which may have a problem that is unsolvable at your end. Not a whole code from `main` that is hard to comprehend.

Comment: This code is part of a long project that's why it's look to messy.The initialization value will be replaced with which we want to modify means status "Not admitted will be change to "admitted" by that initialized value.

Comment: `goto` should definitely raise some flags. I can't help but feel compelled to link the [PHP goto docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) that has a very nice comics about `goto`

Comment: char stat[13];
  
  cout<<"Enter Registration No";
  
  cin>>reg_no;
  
  fstream out("Intermediate.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate|ios::app);
  
  out.seekg(0,ios::beg);
  
  out.read((char*)&std,sizeof(std));
  
  while(!out.eof())
   {  
   
   record_no++;
   
   if(strcmp(std.get_reg_no(),reg_no)==0)
   {
    found=1; 
    break;
    
   } 
   }
  location=(record_no-1)*sizeof(std);
  
  out.seekp(location,ios::beg);
  
  char new_status[]="Addmitted";
  
  strcpy(std.status,new_status);
  
  out.write((char*)&std,sizeof(std));
  out.close();

Answer (score 0):

To modify a text file:

1. Load the file into memory (such as a `std::vector<my_data_struct>`)
2. Modify the data in memory
3. Write the memory to file

You are making some significant mistakes that are costing you:

- Don't use `goto`; there is a better way (subfunctions)
- Don't loop on EOF
- Use `std::string` instead of `char*`
- Modularize, modularize, modularize

That last point needs some additional help: do one thing at a time. Your main code should look something like:

```
get user input (filename, item to modify, etc)

std::vector<items> items = load_file( filename );
auto item = std::find( items.begin(), items.end(), my_search_criterion_predicate );
if (item != items.end())
{
  modify item;
}
write_file( items );

user output
```

All of these will require a little learning on your part, but it is worth the effort.